# Rails: Set a temporary variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, temporary

I need to set a temporary variable (actually more of a "true" or "false") for a view.

The use case is that when a user is created, they are redirected to a dashboard page. For Google AdWords conversion tracking, there is a bit of code that needs to be displayed in the view, but it only should be displayed after the `create` method has been run.

So I'm guessing the way to solve that is to set some temp variable (`@show_conversion` or something) and set it for one view (similar to a flash message).

So, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% unless @user.new_record? %>
<!-- do stuff in here -->

<% end %>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do what I'm asking at all.

Comment: " For Google AdWords conversion tracking, there is a bit of code that needs to be displayed in the view, but it only should be displayed after the create method has been run"  I'm assuming, I guess, that your create method is the ActiveRecord #create method, which saves the record to the database.  #new_record? returns false after the record has an id so you can put your Adwords code inside the guard and it'll run when your record is saved.